# Rails session store stopped working correctly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I have a Rails 3.2 app that uses session store in the controllers to get the user back to the screen they were previously on.

It's been working fine for over a year.  All of a sudden, the production version on Heroku, has started having issues. The user is looking at a `worequest` and clicks on the following in order to add a `comment`.

```
<%= link_to 'New Comment', new_comment_path(:worequest_id => @worequest.id), :class => 'btn btn-primary' %>
```

This is the code I use:

```
 def new
    @comment = Comment.new
    @comment.build_attachment
    @worequest = params[:worequest_id]
    session[:return_to] ||= request.referer

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # new.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @comment }
    end
  end

  # POST /comments
  # POST /comments.json
  def create
    @comment = Comment.new(params[:comment])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @comment.save
        if session[:return_to] != nil
          format.html { redirect_to session.delete(:return_to), notice: 'Comment was successfully created.' }
          format.json { render json: @comment, comment: :created, location: @comment }
        else
          format.html { redirect_to :back, notice: 'Comment was successfully created.' }
          format.json { render json: @comment, comment: :created, location: @comment }
        end
      else
        format.html { render action: "new" }
        format.json { render json: @comment.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

In development and staging (on Heroku), the user goes back to the `worequest` after entering a new `comment`.

Now in Production, the url looks like this:

```
mywebsite/comments instead of mywebsite/worequests/639
```

I'm not even sure where the session[:return_to] gets stored.  Therefore, I'm having trouble debugging the issue.

Thanks for your help!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you able to replicate this behavior 100% of the time, or just seeing it sometimes in your log?

It looks like someone is getting to `comments#new` from /comments (comments#index). Is there a route to /comments?

Run `rake routes` to see all your routes.

If there is a route to comments#index, and there's no reason for it to be exposed because you only intend for people to post comments from within the context of a specific article, consider removing it the comments#index route.

Also, one thing to consider, request.referrer is **not** always available. It's sent by the client who may choose not to send it (e.g. certain privacy extensions remove this header).

Comment: Thanks for the help.  It ended up that the model sends an email and the mailer was getting an error.  I found it in the log - it never displayed on the user's screen.